# Neo4j SDN4 and unicode symbols

Tags: neo4j, character-encoding, opensuse, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm storing the following string with SDN4 in my Neo4j database:

```
Panda Antivirus Pro is the brand’s entry level security product: a powerful antivirus tool that protects your system in an effective – and unobtrusive – way.
```

but after the storing inside of my Neo4j node I have a following:

```
Panda Antivirus Pro is the brand&#xfffd;&#xfffd;&#xfffd;s entry level security product: a powerful antivirus tool that protects your system in an effective &#xfffd;&#xfffd;&#xfffd; and unobtrusive &#xfffd;&#xfffd;&#xfffd; way.
```

In my ogm.properties I have a following properties:

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver
URI=bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost
```

Why I have `&#xfffd;` there instead of a normal characters ?

Locally, at my Windows 10 machine I don't see such issue.. the issue only appears at my Linux openSUSE 42.1 staging environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original string did not have UTF-8 encoding, which neo4j expects, so the characters not in UTF-8 were replaced by the [Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), U+FFFD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to fix this? Why the same code works on my Windows machine and doesn't work on openSUSE ?

Comment: @alexanoid Because different machines have different default settings. For example if you don't explicitly specify the encoding in certain places, the default platform encoding will be used. That might be UTF8 on one machine and something else on another.